# Update Div with CKeditor on click inside toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set up CKEDITOR to update a div with it's current content to create a realtime preview of what's being made. As of right now I have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'content' ,
{   
    allowedContent: true,
    enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
}).on('key',
    function(e){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#content-preview-content").html(CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData());
        },10);
    }
)
CKEDITOR.instances.content.on('contentDom', function() {
    this.document.on('click', function(event){
            $("#content-preview-content").html(CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData());
     });
});

});
```

which works great. The only thing I haven't figured out is how I would get the toolbar function, so that say the were to click on the toolbar and click bold it would then update to bold inside the div. Right now they have to click inside the actual editor or they have to type more content and THEN it would update bold, italic or whatever they added. Does anyone know what the toolbar is called by since hours of googling and testing is getting me no where?